# find: match to column, other than row

Tags: r

I'm working through some reference/match logic and was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to go about this. I've whipped up a tool like this in excel and a limited one in pi, but it would be nice to use r instead so I can tie it into a few other functions I have.

There's a dataframe with three columns: 'table_name', 'columnfriendlyname', and 'iskey'. 
Within 'columnfriendlyname' includes the labels for regular field names, the names of foreign keys, and the names of primary keys.

What the table is supposed to to (hopefully), is append tags into the iskey, using the the nomenclature of the databases labels (found in columnfriendlyname).

The logic goes:

- if in row, columnfriendlyname=table_name, then: is_key
  <-"primary_key"
- if out of row, columnfriendlyname=table_name, then: is_key
  <-"foreign_key"
- if no match at all columnfriendlyname!=table_name, then: is_key <-"non_key"

I created a conditional insert based on the logic in this question here: [R conditional lapply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801951/r-conditional-lapply)

and so far it works great for primary keys:

```
prime<- (dict_data_raw$columnfriendlyname==dict_data_raw$table_name)==TRUE
dict_data_raw$iskey[prime] <-"Primary_key"
```

But now I need to figure out == table_name, but != table_name in row.

Edit: A sample of the data follows, if it helps to clarify:

```
   table_name   columnfriendlyname   is_key
1  address      address           primary_key
2  address      entity            foreign_key
3  address      zip               non_key
4  matter       matter            primary_key
5  matter       address           foreign_key
6  matter       mattertype        non_key
7  entity       entity            primary_key
8  entity       address           foreign_key
9  entity       dob               non_key
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I do net get the expression "in row", "out of row" and "any". Furthermore, the output of `dput(head(dict_data_raw))` or at least a `summary(...)` would help to understand your data structure. Also, `==TRUE` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a little new to the SO formats, and was having trouble wording the logic. To clarify "in row"="columnfriendlyname  matches table_name in row", "out of row" ="columnfriendlyname  matches table_name in column, but not in row row" and "any" was "columnfriendlyname  does not match table_name in column or in row" --thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop that uses `ifelse` like this:

```
for (x in 1:nrow(dict_data_raw)){
  dict_data_raw$iskey[x] <- ifelse(dict_data_raw$columnfriendlyname[x] == dict_data_raw$table_name[x], "primary_key", ifelse(dict_data_raw$columnfriendlyname[x] %in% dict_data_raw$table_name, "foreign_key", "non_key"))
}
```

One row after another, it checks with the first ifelse if the value of columnfriendlyname is equal to table_name, writting "primary_key" if it is and, if it is not, checking with a second ifelse if the value in columnfriendlyname is within all the values in table_name. If it is, writes "foreign_key", if it isn´t, writes "non_key".

`ifelse` checks if a condition is true or false and gives one value or another depending on that. A second `ifelse` can be nested on the false value to solve your question.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This worked perfectly! I tried ifelse before, but I didn't know you could nest  that function. thank you so much for helping out with my column mapping :)

Answer (score 1):

### Using ifelse()

The following code solves your problem

```
u <- unique(dict_data_raw$table_name) # simplifying the table names set
dict_data_raw$is_key <- 
   ifelse(
      dict_data_raw$columnfriendlyname==dict_data_raw$table_name,
      "primary_key", 
      ifelse(
         dict_data_raw$columnfriendlyname %in% u, 
         "foreign_key", 
         "non_key"
      ) 
   )
```

Since **ifelse()** is a vectorized function that takes a *n*-length vector, a logical one, and constructs a *n*-length vector taking the value from the 2nd or the 3rd argument, depending on each value of the 1st argument (either TRUE or FALSE).

### Using for cycle

When using the **for** cycle, it is better to use the **if** construction instead of the **ifelse()** function, in this case the proper code should be

```
u <- unique(dict_data_raw$table_name) # simplifying the table names set
for (i in 1:nrow(dict_data_raw)) {
  dict_data_raw$is_key[i] <- 
    if(dict_data_raw$columnfriendlyname[i]==dict_data_raw$table_name[i]) {
       "primary_key" 
    } else 
       if (dict_data_raw$columnfriendlyname[i] %in% u) {
         "foreign_key" 
       } else  "non_key"
}
```

### Using apply()

Another approach is to use the **apply()** function:

```
u <- unique(dict_data_raw$table_name) # simplifying the table names set
dict_data_raw$is_key <- 
apply(dict_data_raw, 1, function(rrow) if (rrow[1]==rrow[2]) "primary_key" else if(rrow[2] %in% u) "foreign_key" else "non_key")
```

Comment: I really like the Idea of flattening the row into a single vector- thanks for that, it should speed up the loop. Is there a reason why "if" should be used over a nested "ifelse", Especially if it only has three conditions?

Comment: The differences between **ifelse()** and **if** are: (1) **ifelse** is a function wheras **if** is a syntactic construction, (2) **ifelse** takes a vector of *n* logical conditions, and, depending on the value of each conditions, builds a vector of *n answers*, whereas **if** takes a single condition and operates according to such condition. The operation of **if** could be the getting of a value, e.g., `x <- if (cond) a else b`; this property was that I used in the **for** cycle.
**NOTE:** If my aswer was useful to you, please vote my post (push in the up triangle), thanks.